# "Raising your voice". Correct definition and usage

Tags: word-usage

1. Raising your voice is speaking loud and clear (with emphasis), to point something out, mostly in a discussion (e.g. out of excitement).
2. Raising your voice is speaking loud and clear, sharp, more of less angry/aggitated.

I strongly believe option 1 is the only correct definition. I refuse to believe you can only raise your voice in anger.

Enlighten me!

Comment: As I've said a million times, it all depends on context.

Comment: My point exactly: Context, but in most (all documented) cases it's only used in "violent" arguments. I just had a little discussion with a colleague who simply doesn't believe you're able to raise your voice in any other situation. Hence the question.

This might actually belong in psychology...

Comment: _He raised his voice so he could be heard above the din_ is a correct usage of raising your voice

Comment: "I strongly believe option 1 is the only correct definition. I refuse to believe you can only raise your voice in anger." means "I strongly believe option 1 is the only correct definition. I refuse to believe option 2 is the only correct definition." But I believe both definitions are valid in different contexts (maybe not a million).

Comment: 3rd probability is cultural and kind of excitement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best phrase I could come up with that excluded anger was "raised his/her voice in support."   There are a fair number of google hits.  I see there are Ngram instances as well.  I'd certainly suggest that a voice might be raised in situations other than those of anger.